# TFS- Cannot see the Define tab in Test Plans

Tags: azure-devops

In TFS on Microsoft platform cannot see the Define tab in Test Plans although I have the right access. Is there anyone who can help me?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOxtW.png)

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Form [Help me understand the new page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/new-test-plans-page?view=azure-devops#help-me-understand-the-new-page):

> Define tab: Collate, add and manage test cases in a test suite of
>   choice via this tab.

Therefore, you have to use `Basic + Test Plans` or `Visual Studio Enterprise` access level to manage tests in a test plan: [Supported access levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/access-levels?view=azure-devops#supported-access-levels).

---

If you add a screenshot to your question, this will help to see your problem. If you use TFS, it may not include Define tab in Test Plans because it in preview.

For Azure DevOps Services. Check that you have enabled "New Test Plans Page" feature in the preview features:

1. Sign-in into your Azure DevOps Services organization
2. Click on your Avatar on the top right and navigate to "Preview
   Features"
3. Enable the 'New Test Plans Page' feature.

Here you can find some information about the [New Test Plans Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/new-test-plans-page?view=azure-devops).

Comment: I added a screenshot and also checked and I have enabled "New Test Plans Page". Any other idea?

Comment: @Szidonia Which access level (Basic, Basic + Test Plan, VS Enterprise) is assigned to your user?

Comment: Visual Studio Professional.

Comment: @Szidonia to create tests on web you have to use Basic + Test Plans or
Visual Studio Enterprise access level. You can check that here: [Supported access levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/access-levels?view=azure-devops#supported-access-levels)